# How to sort keys/values in Ruby/Rails by file extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Hash that contains filenames.  Each of these filenames have different types of extensions.. i.e. (.txt, .bam, .bam.bai, .fastq, etc) I am trying to figure out a way of iterating over these keys and sorting the list into (3) Three sections based on filename in HTML/erb....  Like this.

Section 1
All FastQ files (.fastq)

Section 2
All .bam and bam.bai files (.bam, .bam.bai)

Section 3
All text files (.txt)

Basically what I have so far is this...

```
<div class="content_box_title">Sequencing Results</div>
  <div class="content_box">
    <% seqfiles = @vmsr_project.seqfiles %>
    <% seqfiles.keys.sort.each do |file|


      fpath = file.to_s

      fsize = File.size(file)
      fdate = File.mtime(file)
      `enter code here`fsize = fsize / 1000000
      fsize = fsize.to_int
      fsize = fsize.to_s
      if fsize == "0" then fsize = "EMPTY or <1" end
      %>
      <div style="float: left">
        <%= link_to File.basename(file), {:action => "send_analysis_file", :project => @vmsr_project[:proj_id], :file => file }, { :onmouseover => "Tip('<div class=\\'tooltip\\'>Click to download. <p style=\\'color: #e26666;\\'>" + fsize + " MB</p></div>', TITLE, 'Download File')", :onmouseout => "UnTip()" } %>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left">
        &nbsp;(<%= fdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>):
      </div>
      <div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= seqfiles[file].join(", ") %>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both; border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">&nbsp;</div>

        <div style="float: left">
         <!--  <%= fpath %> -->
        </div>


    <% end %>

    <% if seqfiles.empty? %>
      <ul><li>None</li></ul>
    <% end %>

  </div>


  <div class="content_box_title">Aligned</div>
  <div class="content_box">
    <p>.bam, .bam.bai files display here</p>

  </div>

  <div class="content_box_title">QC</div>
  <div class="content_box">
    <p>.txt files display here</p>

  </div>
```

As an update everyone... I got the following to work (Please don't laugh, I am a newbie) but the issue is now of course, the header:
    Sequencing Results
prints each time it parses in all three sections.  Definitely need a refactor.

```
<% seqfiles.keys.sort.each do |file|

fpath = file.to_s

fsize = File.size(file)
fdate = File.mtime(file)
fsize = fsize / 1000000
fsize = fsize.to_int
fsize = fsize.to_s
if fsize == "0" then fsize = "EMPTY or <1" end

  case fpath
    when /\.fastq.gz$/ %>
      <div class="content_box_title">Sequencing Results</div>
        <div class="content_box">
          <div style="float: left">
            <%= link_to File.basename(file), {:action => "send_analysis_file", :project => @vmsr_project[:proj_id], :file => file }, { :onmouseover => "Tip('<div class=\\'tooltip\\'>Click to download. <p style=\\'color: #e26666;\\'>" + fsize + " MB</p></div>', TITLE, 'Download File')", :onmouseout => "UnTip()" } %>
          </div>
          <div style="float: left">
            &nbsp;(<%= fdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>):
          </div>
          <div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= seqfiles[file].join(", ") %>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both; border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

  <% when /\.bam(\.bai)?$/ %>
      <div class="content_box_title">Aligned</div>
        <div class="content_box">
          <div style="float: left">
            <%= link_to File.basename(file), {:action => "send_analysis_file", :project => @vmsr_project[:proj_id], :file => file }, { :onmouseover => "Tip('<div class=\\'tooltip\\'>Click to download. <p style=\\'color: #e26666;\\'>" + fsize + " MB</p></div>', TITLE, 'Download File')", :onmouseout => "UnTip()" } %>
          </div>
          <div style="float: left">
            &nbsp;(<%= fdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>):
          </div>
          <div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= seqfiles[file].join(", ") %>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both; border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>

  <% else %>
      <div class="content_box_title">QC</div>
        <div class="content_box">
          <div style="float: left">
            <%= link_to File.basename(file), {:action => "send_analysis_file", :project => @vmsr_project[:proj_id], :file => file }, { :onmouseover => "Tip('<div class=\\'tooltip\\'>Click to download. <p style=\\'color: #e26666;\\'>" + fsize + " MB</p></div>', TITLE, 'Download File')", :onmouseout => "UnTip()" } %>
          </div>
          <div style="float: left">
            &nbsp;(<%= fdate.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>):
          </div>
          <div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= seqfiles[file].join(", ") %>
          </div>
          <div style="clear: both; border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if seqfiles.empty? %>
  <ul><li>None</li></ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You may want to check [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are missing an example of your hash and what your output should be. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Also, don't fill your view with code. That should be performed in your controller, and the results assigned to a variable which is then accessed in the view. Don't write Rails views like you would old PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Just separate filenames into 3 arrays and then iterate each.

```
<% separated = seqfiles.keys.sort.inject({}){|h,key|
  case key.to_s
  when /\.fastq$/
    h[:fastq] ||= []
  when /\.bam(\.bai)?$/
    h[:bam] ||= []
  else
    h[:other] ||= []
  end.push(key)
  h
} %>

<% separated[:fastq].each do |file| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<% separated[:bam].each do |file| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<% separated[:other].each do |file| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is extremely clever.  Thanks so much!  Also thanks Wand Maker and Tin man for their suggestions.  The first part of the code seems to work, or at least doesn't throw and exception.... but when I try to do the iteration, it seems to be nil Class?

Comment: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: <% separated[:fastq].each do |file|  file_name = file.to_s
21:         puts file_name
22:      end %>

Comment: just check if `separated[:fastq]` is present, the same applies for others

Comment: Just to be safe...  the project I am working on is very very old... it's ruby 1.8, and Rails 2.3.  Will the code above even work in Rails 2.3?

Comment: it is pure ruby and does not use any new features, should work (but of course - test everything before deploying to production)

Comment: Thanks a bunch Vasfed.  I also updated code above.  I am not sure why :fastq would be nil... I have test files created for all the types, so it should populate the array.  I updated code above to get something working, but of course it's printing the header out every time it goes through the loop which is not good :)

Comment: Also... the hash is actually in the model.  So, that might be part of the issue... the code is very old and whacked.

Comment: Got it!  You are correct.  It doesn't necessarily iterate over all three at once.  As it iterates... .fastq could be nil at iteration 1, and .bam have a value,  and then .fastq could hold a value on the second iteration and .bam be nil.   It took me a while to understand.  Thanks for your help Vasfed!

Comment: Actually I am incorrect in my assumption above Vasfed... it does iterate over each one... BUT,  the model adds .gz to fastq files.... so it was testing for .fastq, when it is actually building a .fastq.gz file.  Once this was added nil is not an issue,  but probably should do some error checking for nil in case something doesn't get populated to catch the exception.  Thanks again!